# Access aws root user using aws educate

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, settings

I am curently using aws educate account and I access the aws console manager through vacareum but my user seems to be a federated user and so i can't launch a a aws template stack in cloudformation due to restrictions, and for that reason I would like to ask you either how to access the root user or how to give to the federated user admin previleges.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to access the root user how to give to the federated user admin previleges

Unfortunately, you **can't access** root account on AWS Educate Starter Accounts nor **elevate** your own privileges. You can check what is allowed below:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

The only thing you can do, if you don't want to use own private account, is to contact their support and ask if they can modify your permissions for you.

Comment: @AbdelhamidSajid No problem. Hopefully they can help with extra permissions.